# org-capture evaluate each time without currying

Tags: org-mode, backquote

Recently my org-mode config broke. And i started using `` ` `` and `,` to get it to work again. But now i have the issue that a function call `(dl/capture-report-date-file)` gets evaluated once and curries the time value (which is the time, and should be dynamic) for all future captures. I'd like it to get evaluated each time I capture, and have a different date each time. I am not an elisp dev.

```
(with-eval-after-load "org"
  (setq org-capture-templates
        `(("c" "manual-headline" entry
           (file ,(dl/capture-report-date-file
                   (concat org-directory "/notes")))
           "* SOON %?     \n:PROPERTIES:\n:CREATED: %U\n:SOURCE: %a\n:END:\n\n%i\n"))))
```

Comment: I use this for my time-stamp `<%<%Y-%m-%d %a 08:30>>` inside the `org-capture-templates`.  It uses the standard format options and could use the current time instead of 08:30 if you prefer.  See the doc-string of the *variable* `format-time-string` for formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

According to [`(info "(org) Template elements")`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html), when setting capture target, instead of supplying a filename, you can also use a function:

> `(function function-finding-location)`
>
> Most general way: write your own
>   function which both visits the file and moves point to the right
>   location.

You can take a look at the following as an example, it picks a filename base on the current time.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("c" "manual-headline" entry
         (function
          (lambda ()
            (let ((filename (format-time-string "/tmp/%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M.org")))
              (set-buffer (find-file-noselect filename))
              (goto-char (point-max)))))
         "* SOON %? %U")))
```